# Data Collection reports fail because login is from an untrusted domain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, reporting, data-collection

I've set up a data warehouse and Data Collection according to BO. Reports are generated properly when running them in Management Studio running on the server but fail when they are run from Management Studio on a different machine (which is using VPN to connect to the network the SQL Server is on). The error message is:

> Failed to connect to server x.x.x.x. --> Login failed. The login is
>   from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows
>   authentication.

The server uses mixed mode authentication. Data Collection is configured to use an SQL Login and the login that tries to generate the report is an SQL Login as well. They've got nothing to do with domains. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Are the two computers in the same domain?

Comment: I've got no idea where VPN puts the connecting computer but I suppose they aren't. Otherwise it would not be an untrusted domain, would it? Why is that even important? I'm not trying to use Windows authentication. I guess I'm missing some major details about how this thing works...

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the Windows principal that's implicitly used when you open Management Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Jon, that's interesting. I wonder why does it not complain about when I'm simply connecting to the server and run a query. Any idea how to solve that? I'm not the sharpest knife in the drawer when it comes to domains :) Is it absolutely necessary for the computers to be in the same domain? What happens when there's VPN involved?

Comment: VPN is a networking construct to join multiple separate networks as if they were one, so that shouldn't affect anything. It's still unclear to me what the domain topology is like on your network... Is the SQL Server box in a different domain than your workstation?

Comment: The topology is... complicated, at least :) Not only in different domains but the networks belong to different companies as well. The workstation is on the network of the company I work for. The network the SQL Server is on belongs to another company. And to add some more confusion, the workstation is used with a local login.

Comment: Complicated is fine, I just need to understand it. :) How are the reports being run? SSRS? Stored procedures fed into something else? ...?

Comment: I appreciate your inclination to help me, Jon, thank you very much. The reports are (or should) be retrieved by opening Management in Object Explorer, right clicking on Data Collection, then selecting Reports->Management Data Warehouse->Disk Usage Summary (eg.). I've got no knowledge about how the rest internally happens.

Comment: Oh right, Data Collector, sorry. Hmmm... okay. This is probably a permissions issue with how you're logged into SQL Server. Are you using a SQL login to connect to the server, or Windows Authentication? If it's the latter, try running Management Studio itself under the domain account you use to log in to the SQL Server box (Shift+Right-Click on the shortcut, select Run As Different User) and see if that works.

Comment: That's why I find this weird. I'm not using Windows Authentication and I don't even know how it gets involved here. The SQL Server is running on a computer on the network of the other company. The network of our company is connected to that one using VPN. The workstation is on the network of our company but it is using a local account (I don't know if that's important or not). Management Studio is running on this machine and it connects to the SQL Server using an SQL Login. Other reports (like those for the server itself or for databases) are running properly.

Comment: Right, but when you run the reports locally (they work), you log in using a different Windows account (correct?). Try starting Management Studio using that account like I suggested and see what happens -- there are other features in SQL Server that grab that information (Maitenance Plans, for example) when you don't expect it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to suggest me to do :( There are no different Windows accs on the workstation. And there are no SQL servers installed on it either, it only has the Management Studio. Its sole purpose is to connect to SQL Servers on different networks. Both reports (Data Collection or otherwise) are invoked on the workstation and fetch data from other machine. With the only difference that one of them works while the other one does not.

Comment: You said that running the reports directly on the SQL box works, correct? To do that, I assume you had to log in to the SQL box using a different Windows account than you use on your workstation. Use the instructions I provided a few comments back to start Management Studio running under that same account.

Comment: Oh, okay, it's clear now :) That's not possible at the moment. The SQL box was reached through a remote desktop connection by another developer when I asked him to try it locally. I've no direct access to the box itself, no account, no password whatsoever. Also, I didn't know it was possible to start an application on a computer using a login from another machine/domain!? Why is that necessary?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4242/discussion-between-gemisigo-and-jon-seigel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed this is an issue with how the reports get executed on the server -- I reproduced the issue exactly by using two virtual machines, neither of which was in a domain.

Moreover, I created a test user (member of the Users built-in group and nothing more) on the SQL box, ran Management Studio locally as that user, logged in with `sa`, and attempted to run the report. As I expected, it failed, and returned the error `Failed to connect to server MDWTestSQL. --> Login failed for user 'MDWTESTSQL\TestUser'`.

This is clear indication that the reports are implemented to only use Windows authentication for some portion of it. Therefore, sufficient SQL-level permissions must be granted to the Windows principal running Management Studio, even if you authenticate to the server using a SQL login.

There are two workarounds:

1. Use pass-through authentication: create a matching (user name and password) *local* login on the *workstation*, and impersonate the local login to run Management Studio remotely. (I tested that this works.)
2. Use pass-through authentication by creating new matching local accounts on both boxes, and set up SQL permissions for the new account.

As I mentioned in chat, this problem is "fixed" in the 2012 Management Studio -- the reports in the menu are hidden if the Windows account doesn't have permissions to run the reports.

Comment: Yes, the issue and its reasons have been ascertained yet I still have troubles with the workarounds. I don't understand the first one and cannot get the second one to work.

Comment: @gemisigo: See edit. I realized that workaround #1 would require that you know the password to that account.

Comment: You're helping me a lot, Jon, thanks. I was able to accomplish #3 and while I'm pretty happy it works, I'm aiming at #2. A domaint acc was created and added to SQL Server with the required permissions but the problems start earlier. I cannot run anything on the workstation (with local login) trying different user using mydomain\mydomainuser for account. Not even Calculator is willing to start. I suppose I don't fully understand what 'impersonate it remotely' mean.

Comment: @gemisigo: Sorry, my bad. Cross-domain impersonation requires domain trusts to set up, which you don't have and can't do. You're now at the optimal solution with new matching local logins (the new domain account can be removed).

Comment: Oh, I see. Or at least I think so. So, if I have two logins, both alike in dignity, I mean matching username AND password, one on the SQL box and the other one on the workstation (expediently, duplicating the one on the workstation to the SQL box), and giving it the required SQL permissions then I'll be able to run the reports, regardless of how restricted that login is in Windows on the SQL box, right?

Comment: @gemisigo: Correct -- this is called pass-through authentication. I tested this using a regular user on the SQL box with minimal permissions and it worked fine.

Comment: Then it seems this is the best I can get from the current environment. Thanks for the thorough explanation and most of all, the time you spent on me, Jon.